# delete_cookies() helper not working in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, cookies, codeigniter-4

I want to create a remember me feature on my website using cookie.
when the user logout i want to destroy all session and cookies.
But the problem is i can't delete existing cookie.

i'am using CodeIgniter 4 framework

i already loaded cookie helper in my BaseController.
i tried this code in my logout controller :

```
delete_cookie('remember_me_token');
```

but that doesnt work, and also i tried this one :

```
set_cookie('remember_me_token', '', - 1209600); // set to minus
```

and the result is the same, i can't delete the cookie

please help :(

Comment: How did you create your cookie in the first place? First thing that comes to my mind is that you're not deleting the cookie in the right path or did not created him with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I followed up with a different approach using the setCookie function which was chained using the response and simply set the expiry time to -1.

```
$this->response->setCookie(['name'   => 'token','value'  => "" ,'expire' => '-1','domain' => $domain, 'path'   => '/'])
```

Reference : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/response.html?highlight=set%20cookie